# What is the difference in running a rails unit test with -Ilib and -Itest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, command-line

I use both the following commands to run tests in my application:

```
ruby -Ilib test/unit/account_test.rb
ruby -Itest test/unit/account_test.rb
```

Both works fine. But, what is the difference. What actually the flag `-I` means?

Comment: [Ruby Command Line Options](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_command_line_options.htm)

Comment: i guess iTest invented by steve jobes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Ruby manual page (`man ruby`):

```
 -I directory   Used to tell Ruby where to load the library scripts.  Direc‐
                tory path will be added to the load-path variable ($:).
```

The variable `$:` (aliased as `$LOAD_PATH`) is the array of directories where Ruby looks for files to load when you call `require`. In your case both commands works well because, I guess, you don't require anything inside `lib` or `test` directories from your test code.

Comment: But why `-Itest` is wittren like that, It shouldn't be  `-I test`? the space between the is optional?